# Check the current Item of a QML StackView

Tags: qt, qml

I have a main page containing a `StackView` with multiples pages: *Main Menu*, *param1Page*, *param2Page*, ….

I want to display a home button to the main page if the activated item is not "*Main Menu*".

```qml
Item
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    StackView
    {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: mainmenuPage
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

  
    Component
    {
        id : mainmenuPage

        ColumnLayout
        {
            id : mainmenuColumnLayout
            TitleText
            {
                text: qsTr("Main menu")
                Layout.preferredHeight: 50
            }
            GridView
            {
                id: grid2
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                cellWidth: parent.width / 4
                cellHeight: 150
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                interactive: false
                focus: true

                model: model
                delegate: Item
                {
                    width: grid2.cellWidth;
                    height: grid2.cellHeight
                    UserButton
                    {
                        picto: symbol
                        text: title
                        enabled: isEnabled
                        font.family: Fonts.icons
                        height: 120
                        width: 140
                        pixelSize: textSize
                        onClicked: model.goToSettingsItem(type)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component
    {
        id : param1Page
        Loader
        {
            id: param1Loader
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "Param1.qml"
        }
    }

    Component
    {
        id : param2Page
        Loader
        {
            id: param1Loader
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "Param2.qml"
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I use the property `currentItem` (it represents the currently visible item in the `StackView`).

Customized Button:

```qml
PushButton
{
    visible: stackView.currentItem !== mainmenuPage
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
    font.family: Fonts.icons
    text: "\uF015" //Home
    font.pixelSize: 24
    onClicked: {
        model.goToMainMenu()
    }
}
```

*Problem:*  Even though the `currentItem` is the `mainmenuPage`, the button is still displayed.

I tried to debug as below:

```javascript
console.log("Current item:", stackView.currentItem) // Current item: QQuickColumnLayout(0x5c115150)
```

I deduce that the `currentItem` contains the content of the component.

I want to check what the `currentItem` is and run a comparison `stack.currentItem !== mainmenuPage`.

Comment: `mainmenuPage` is not an instance of `ColumnLayout`. Try using `Page` as the component's root and then set its `title` property. Alternatively, you can set the `objectName` property of `ColumnLayout` and use it to check if it is the main page. (i.e `ColumnLayout { objectName:'main-page' }`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Component`s don't really work like this - they're kind of more like a Class definition that gets instantiated by other widgets. So, `mainmenuPage` is itself not an instance, and its contents/children are what is instantiated by the StackView. As such, there can be multiple instances of the `mainmenuPage` and its children, and thus the ids are scoped only inside the `Component`, and won't work outside of it.

As a work around, I suggest you add an `objectName` to your `Component`'s contents for the comparison. Here is a standalone example:

```
    StackView {
        id: stack
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: mainmenuPage
    }
    
    Text {
        text: "Visibility Test"
        y: 30
        visible: stack.currentItem.objectName == 'mainmenuPageNAME'
    }
    
    Component {
        id : mainmenuPage

        Text {
            id: innerText
            text: "Stack Component"
            objectName: 'mainmenuPageNAME'
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the visibility test successfully passes the objectName comparison test, and is shown:

[image: visibility test appears]

Of course, there are other considerations when using this approach, like whether or not you are going to instantiate multiple instances of `mainmenuPage` and if the objectName must be unique. Though I am guessing this is not a problem.